# OpenGL FPS Camera movement relative to lookAt target

Tags: math, opengl, perspectivecamera

I have a camera in OpenGL.I had no problem with it until adding FPS controller.The problem is that the basic FPS behavior is ok. The camera moves forward,backward,left and right+ rotates towards the direction supplied by mouse input.The problems begin when the camera moves to the sides or the back of the target position.In such a case camera local forward,backward,left,right directions aren't updated based on its current forward look but remain the same as if it was right in front of the target.Example:
If the target object position is at (0,0,0) and camera position is at (-50,0,0) (to the left of the target) and camera is looking at the target,then to move it back and forth I have to use the keys for left and right movement while backward/forward keys move the camera sideways.
Here is the code I use to calculate camera position, rotation and LookAt matrix:

```
void LookAtTarget(const vec3 &eye,const  vec3 &center,const  vec3 &up)
{


    this->_eye = eye;
    this->_center = center;
    this->_up = up;
    this->_direction =normalize((center - eye)); 

    _viewMatrix=lookAt( eye,  center , up);
    _transform.SetModel(_viewMatrix );
    UpdateViewFrustum();
}

void SetPosition(const vec3 &position){
    this->_eye=position;
    this->_center=position + _direction;
    LookAtTarget(_eye,_center,_up);
}
void SetRotation(float rz , float ry ,float rx){
    _rotationMatrix=mat4(1);
    vec3 direction(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    vec3 up(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    _rotationMatrix=eulerAngleYXZ(ry,rx,rz);
    vec4 rotatedDir= _rotationMatrix * vec4(direction,1) ;
    this->_center = this->_eye + vec3(rotatedDir);

    this->_up =vec3( _rotationMatrix * vec4(up,1));

    LookAtTarget(_eye, _center, up);


}
```

Then in the render loop I set camera's transformations:

```
 while(true)
{
    display();
    fps->print(GetElapsedTime());
    if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) || !glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED)){
        break;
    }

    calculateCameraMovement();

    moveCamera();

    view->GetScene()->GetCurrentCam()->SetRotation(0,-camYRot,-camXRot);

    view->GetScene()->GetCurrentCam()->SetPosition(camXPos,camYPos,camZPos);

}
```

lookAt() method comes from [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) math lib.
I am pretty sure I have to multiply some of the vectors (eye ,center etc) with rotation matrix but I am not sure which ones.I tried to multiply  _viewMatrix by the _rotationMatrix but it creates a mess.The code for FPS camera position and rotation calculation is taken from [here](http://r3dux.org/2011/05/simple-opengl-keyboard-and-mouse-fps-controls/).But for the actual rendering I use programmable pipeline.

**Update:**
I solved the issue by adding a separate method which doesn't calculate camera matrix using lookAt but rather using the usual and basic approach:

```
void FpsMove(GLfloat x, GLfloat y , GLfloat z,float pitch,float yaw){
    _viewMatrix =rotate(mat4(1.0f), pitch, vec3(1, 0, 0));
    _viewMatrix=rotate(_viewMatrix, yaw, vec3(0, 1, 0));
    _viewMatrix= translate(_viewMatrix, vec3(-x, -y, -z));
    _transform.SetModel( _viewMatrix );
}
```

It solved the problem but I still want to know how to make it work with lookAt() methods I presented here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the forward direction of the camera, which is presumably fixed to `(0,0,-1)`. You can do this by rotating the directions about the y axis by camYRot (as computed in the lookat function) so that forwards is in the same direction that the camera is pointing (in the plane made by the z and x axes).

Comment: The direction is represented by _center vector.It does gets updated and camera rotates according to mouse input direction so I am not sure that is the problem..